# Get RowsWise data with Columns Name ColumnWise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table Structure like:

```
    ApplicationId   IsFO20Submitted IsFO08Submitted IsFO07Submitted IsFO09Submitted IsFO10Submitted
    CBA202000001            Y             Y               Y                Y               Y
    CBA202000002            Y             Y               Y                Y               Y
    CBA202000007            Y             Y               Y                Y               Y
```

I want my Result to be like:

```
    ApplicationId   CBA202000001    CBA202000002    CBA202000007
    IsFO20Submitted       Y              Y               Y
    IsFO08Submitted       Y              Y               Y
    IsFO07Submitted       Y              Y               Y
    IsFO09Submitted       Y              Y               Y
    IsFO10Submitted       Y              Y               Y
```

Is there anything i can try in SQL to get such result

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: am using SQLServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT  TT.ApplicationId,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.ApplicationId = 'CBA202000001' then ApplicationVal END) AS [CBA202000001],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.ApplicationId = 'CBA202000002' then ApplicationVal END) AS [CBA202000002],
        MAX(CASE WHEN t.ApplicationId = 'CBA202000007' then ApplicationVal END) AS [CBA202000002]
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('IsFO20Submitted', IsFO20Submitted), 
              ('IsFO08Submitted',IsFO08Submitted),
               . . .
              ('IsFO10Submitted',IsFO10Submitted) 
     ) TT(ApplicationId, ApplicationVal)
GROUP BY TT.ApplicationId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check pivot - unpivot function. You'll have to do the unpivot first and then pivot the result. Didn't test it though so you'll have to try it first...

Pivot example:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT column1, column2
  FROM tables
  WHERE conditions
)
PIVOT 
(
  aggregate_function(column2)
  FOR column2
  IN ( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n) | subquery
)
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ];
```

Unpivot example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unpivot_test
UNPIVOT (quantity FOR product_code IN (product_code_a AS 'A', product_code_b AS 'B', product_code_c AS 'C', product_code_d AS 'D'));
```

Comment: Product specific tip, to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP which dbms this is for.

Comment: Please study my Question, Pivot only Converts Columns to Rows, I want Column Names with there Values for Specific ID